# Using PowerShell to count unique error messages in a log file

Tags: powershell

I have several logs files with hundreds of lines in the following format:

```
{"time": 0800, "service":"A service", "id": 5, "error":"bad"}  
{"time": 0900, "service":"B service", "id": 6, "error":"good"}
```

I'd like to be able run through each file and output a table with a count of each unique error message .. something like this:

Error "bad" came up 5 times

Error "good" came up 3 times

I'm not sure if converting the content to JSON makes sense in this situation, but I have done the following so far to at least identify unique strings:

```
Get-Childitem -path "\path" | Select-string -Pattern "good"
```

and that gives me all the "good" messages.

It would seem to me that using a loop with a counter to capture unique events could be used. What would be the best way to achieve all of this with PowerShell?

Comment: Just a headsup, you can pipe your Command to `Measure-Object` and it will return you the number of lines.

Answer (score 4):

Convert the json strings in the file into objects with `ConvertFrom-Json` and then group them by the `error` property using `Group-Object`:

```
Get-Childitem -path "\path" |ConvertFrom-Json |Group-Object error -NoElement
```

Comment: @Avshalom Argh, sorry dude, story of my life :-P

Comment: great, that worked.  One of the files is formatted in a way where the convertfrom-json cmdlet doesn't like it.  There is only one line and it is like this, { "error" : "bad"},  but it is spread out on 3 lines.  The error thrown is "Invalid object passed in ':' or '}".  How can I skip files where the json is not recognized.. or how can I change it so it is recognized?  Second follow up question.  How can I access the properties of the object?  For example, I want to display the "service" and "time" properties.  I only get count, group, and name.