# ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected

Tags: json, powershell, scripting

Earlier this week, I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650319/using-powershell-to-count-unique-error-messages-in-a-log-file/51650491#51650491) to find the best way to go through a directory of text files with log information in JSON format and count how many of each unique messages there are.

I was able to do so with the answers provided.  However, the problem I'm having now is that one of the files is formatted in a way that ConvertFrom-JSON doesn't like.  It throws the error:

> ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected.

Initially, I thought I could use 'erroraction -silentlycontinue' to skip that file and move on (there's just one line with nothing meaningful in it).  However, it appears to be a [known issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2860) that this doesn't work with ConvertFrom-JSON and the alternative is to use a Try / Catch.

How would I use a try / catch to bypass the one bad file?  Or is there another way to cleanly skip this file without having to remove it from the directory?

Here is what I have started out with.  It's not much, but some guidance on this would be great.  I have also seen some info online that I would use `gc -Raw` or `Out-string` before the ConvertFrom-JSON, but that gave me the same result.

```
try {
 gci -Path "path" | gc | ConvertFrom-Json | Group-Object message -NoElement
}

catch {
 write-host "can't convert file to JSON"
}

finally {

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to insert your error handling into the pipeline. This is where [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) will come in handy:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "path" | 
    ForEach-Object -Process {
        try {
            $_ | Get-Content | ConvertFrom-Json
        } catch {
            write-host "can't convert file '$_' to JSON"
        }
    } | Group-Object message -NoElement
```

The successful conversions will be passed through.

Additionally, consider using `Write-Warning` instead of `Write-Host` for your error condition. It seems to best fit this situation, and can be redirected or opted out by an invoker.

If you think this condition is even less serious than a warning, consider `Write-Verbose` so invokers can opt in instead.

Comment: @LotPings true, that's a small enough change to put in the code I think, so I edited that in. And you're right about the grouping, so I've put that on the outside of the loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The answer worked for me
[ConvertFrom-Json cannot read my JSON](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/ask_the_experts/f/learn_powershell_from_don_jones-24/12966/convertfrom-json-cannot-read-my-json)

Use the `-Raw` parameter of the `Get-Content` cmdlet, otherwise `Get-Conten`t reads each line separately and it will be stored in the variable as an array.

```
$json = Get-Content c:\temp\net\cars.json -Raw
ConvertFrom-Json $json
```

Try this and you will end up with a nicely usable object:

```
$cars = Get-Content c:\temp\net\cars.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json | Select -ExpandProperty cars
```

Comment: It might be good to note that `-raw` is not required on at least PS 5.1 (4.0 definitely needs it).